# Migrating from qmail/courier to postfix/dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot, email, migration

I was wondering if it was at all possible to take mail messages from an old vpopmail Maildir and put them into a new dovecot Maildir without editing settings in the new installation (as the new system is web managed now and I don't want it to fall out of sync!)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. And if you had looked at the documentation, you would have seen the guide: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration/Courier

Comment: hmm must have missed that. this is what happens when you rely on google instead of common sense (going directly to the page of the project you use)